# Android email app like notification

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to add some kind of notification in app image (Like in email app when a new message arrives it will show it in app icon) ? If yes please suggest me some examples..Thanks

Comment: try looking into `BroadcastReceiver`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use notification service in your app below link can help you

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 1):

yes it is possible to add icon on your notification

Use like this

```
Notification appNotification = new Notification(
                R.drawable.notification_icon, "inspirationQday alert...",
                System.currentTimeMillis());
```